# Java Web scraping with proxies

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, httprequest

I' currently working on a website scraping service with all that goes with it (rotating proxies , rotating user agent, random delays). 
It works for me when the amount of concurrency requests is low (up to 4). But when I increase the concurrency, after some time I get blocked by the webpage. But it dont't block just one proxy, but rather all other proxies even if it is used the first time. I would like to understand how they can find out? Can I prevent by set some further entries in the request header and rotating them? 
Thanks in advance!